# How can I correct my Java code ?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have written this Java program that resizes and displays an image located in C:/, and closes in five seconds of it being displayed. Although the class compiles correctly, I am unable to close it (not hide it) after five seconds. 
Here is the code :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
public class loadscreen extends JFrame 
{
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private static JFrame JFrame1;
    //Constructor 
    public loadscreen()
    {
        final BufferedImage img=new ImgUtils().scaleImage(750,500,"C:/default_logo_img.jpg");
        this.setTitle(" sCool ");
        this.setSize(750,500);
        //pane with null layout
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,500));
        contentPane.setBackground(new Color(255,255,255));
        JLabel label=new JLabel(new ImageIcon((Image)img));
        //adding components to contentPane panel
        contentPane.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //adding panel to JFrame and seting of window position and close operation
        this.add(contentPane);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);
        JFrame1 = this;
    }

    public static void main()
    {
        System.setProperty("swing.defaultlaf", "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {
                    new loadscreen();
                }
            });
        loadscreen.closeCall();
    }

    public static void closeCall()
    {
        Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
        int time = today.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int time2 = time + 5;
        for(int i=1; i>0; i++)
        {
            if (today.get(Calendar.SECOND) == time2)
            {
                JFrame1.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(JFrame1, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Use a Swing Timer, not an infinite for loop.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: Note : It is incomplete. I just need the part where it closes (not hides) in five seconds.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, could you explain that with an example of how I should implement it ? I'm starting to learn swing, and I don't know that much of anything yet. These were all edits made to a basic program given by my friend.

Comment: Google the Swing Timer tutorial as it's all well explained there. Edit: [here's the link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: Thanks, but the exiting part isn't working, @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: *"the exiting part isn't working"*  Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) of your attempt as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29194160/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of writing a solution for your problem is kind of dirty to professional programmers, but since you are a beginner, I'll just fix your code with some small changes :-)

Only your method `closeCall()` needs some adjustment:

```
public static void closeCall()
{
    Long exitTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime() + 5 * 1000;
    for(int i=1; i>0; i++)
    {
        Long currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
        if (currentTime >= exitTime)
        {
            JFrame1.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(JFrame1, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        }        
    }
}
```

I'm using `Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()` to get the current time in milliseconds. We need to add 5 seconds, so that's 5 * 1000 in milliseconds. In the loop, whenever the currentTime is larger than the exitTime, the screen is closed.